# mouse copy paste in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

When I select text with the mouse, I see a region being selected.
However, when I release the mouse, the selection goes away.

Is there a simple way in spacemacs to use the mouse to defin a region, where the mark is set upon the "down" mouse button, and the end is marked with the "up" button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually, it is this way (marking via dragging with mouse1 pressed), and the mark should stay when you release the button –– unless you accidentally click again with any button (eg. tapping the right button with the small finger without wanting to to so) or move the text cursor.

Is this a general problem, or does it occur just occasionally?  In the first case, some things need to be configured; in the latter it is quite likely that you accidentally remove the region yourself.

Comment: Thank you. As I knew it was supposed to work, I upgraded emacs to 25.3. I guess it was a bug in the particular version I was using